# Syncronisize two looping Java-Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Two threads are running parallel:

Thread1:

```
while(...) {
  <-- wait until thread2 is not in update()
  doWork();
}
```

Thread2:

```
while(...) {
  doWork();
  <-- wait until thread1 is not in work()
  update();
}
```

I think the examples above explain what I try to do, but I have not really an idea how to do this synchronization. The `update()`-method of `thread2` is critical an while it is executed `thread2` have to wait.

Edit:

Thanks so far for the answers. More than one is working well. I was asked what I am trying to do and I want to give an short update for that.

Based on the `currentState` thread2 calculates the `nextState` and swap both before it repeats calculating endless. thread1 displays the 'currentState' in the gui for the user.

Thread1 should not display the `currentState` while the swaping is currently in progress.

Thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use locks (look at the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package) but I'd first think about whether the approach in general could be improved, e.g. with lock-free algorithms etc.

Another way could be the use of `synchronized` methods/blocks on a shared object. That all depends on what you're actually trying to achieve, however.

Example for using a `synchronized` block:

T1:

```
while(...) {
  synchronized( SomeClass.class ) {
    doWork();
  }
}
```

T2:

```
while(...) {
  doWork();
  synchronized( SomeClass.class ) {
    update();
  }
}
```

Here you'd synchronize on the same instance of `Class<SomeClass>` which would work as long you're using the same classloader.

Keep in mind that you should make the synchronized blocks as small as possible in order to not add unnecessary blocking.

Besides that, note that the synchronized block in T1 might make it hard for T2 to break in between two iterations. The question, however, would be why it is designed that way.

**Edit**

As an alternative to synchronizing the entire `doWork()` call you might want to think about what actually needs to be synchronized.

As an example, take the following pseudo code:

```
  WorkResult doWork(SharedObject so) {
    Data data = so.loadData();
    WorkResult wr = doSomeLengthyWork(data);
    return wr;
  }

  void update(WorkResult wr, SharedObject so) {
    so.updateFromWorkResult( wr );
  }
```

If your situation is like this, you could just synchronize the calls to `so.loadData()` and `so.updateFromWorkResult()` and let the lengthy operation work on a copy of the data provided by `so.loadData()`.

**Edit 2:**

Alternatively you could use a `ReadWriteLock` implementation:

```
T1:

while(...) {
  Lock readlock = readWriteLock.readLock();
  readlock.lock();

  doWork();

  readlock.unlock();  
}
```

T2:

```
while(...) {
  doWork();

  Lock writelock= readWriteLock.writeLock();
  writelock.lock();

  update();

  writelock.unlock();
}
```

Note that I left exception handling etc. out for simplicity.

What you're basically doing here is aquire a read lock during work and a write lock while updating. Multiple threads can work in parallel unless there's a write lock (multiple read locks are allowed) and updates would wait until all read locks have been released. To achieve this you could use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` in fair mode which should issue the locks in the order they are requested, i.e. when T2 asks for a lock while T1 is still reading it will get the lock next, despite T1 immediately asking for the lock again.

Comment: This is only working if I put a Thread.sleep() behind the synchronisized-block in T1.

Comment: @doev yes, that's true and the reason I wrote `That all depends on what you're actually trying to achieve`. Without more information it's hard to give _exact_ advice and the example above was just meant to be an example. I'll add some more info though.

Comment: The words "lock-free" and "wait" don't belong together.  An algorithm is "lock free" if the failure of one thread to make progress will not prevent any other thread from making progress.  In this case, there is an explicit requirement that the two threads take turns waiting for each other.  Any time one thread waits for another, the system is, by definition, not lock-free.

Comment: I have to correct me. It is working without the sleep(), but then T2 is waiting most time on T1. And I agree, for deeper discussion I have to write some example code.

Comment: @jameslarge In fact by mentioning lock-free approaches I was questioning the requirement for the two threads waiting on each other in general.

Comment: @doev it's not necessarily about example code but a description of what you're trying to achieve in general. I have the strong feeling that the approach in general could be improved. Questions that I'd ask myself: Why is one thread responsible for updating and the other is not? What do they do in their work methods that could interfere with the updates? etc.

Comment: I wrote a short explanation in the question about what I try to do.

Comment: @doev thx for the explanation, this makes it clearer now. Please have a look at my "Edit 2": you'd want to use a read-write lock. That would enable you to use multiple reader threads concurrently as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `Lock` would be the easiest approach. Here's a demo of how simple it is. We create two `Runnable` and start them running under two threads. We then wait for 30 seconds and then interrupt them and wait for them to finish.

```
// Lock shared between both threads.
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
// Random numbers.
final Random random = new Random();

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    // Process 1 is a runnable.
    Runnable p1 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Grab the lock.
                    lock.lock();
                    // Do my work.
                    doWork();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("P1 Interrupted!");
                    break;
                } finally {
                    // Release the lock in a `finally` to ensure it can never be left locked.
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }

        private void doWork() throws InterruptedException {
            long wait = random.nextInt(2000);
            System.out.println("P1 Working ... " + wait);
            // Wait up to 2 seconds.
            Thread.sleep(wait);
            System.out.println("P1 Work done");
        }

    };

    Runnable p2 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Do my work.
                    doWork();
                    // Grab the lock.
                    lock.lock();
                    // Do my update.
                    update();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("P2 Interrupted!");
                    break;
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }

        private void doWork() throws InterruptedException {
            long wait = random.nextInt(2000);
            System.out.println("P2 Working ... " + wait);
            // Wait up to 2 seconds.
            Thread.sleep(wait);
            System.out.println("P2 Work done");
        }

        private void update() throws InterruptedException {
            long wait = random.nextInt(2000);
            System.out.println("P2 Update ... " + wait);
            // Wait up to 2 seconds.
            Thread.sleep(wait);
            System.out.println("P2 Update done");
        }

    };

    // Create the two threads.
    Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
    // Start them up.
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    // Wait 30 seconds - with narrative.
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Tick");

    }
    // Stop them.
    t1.interrupt();
    t2.interrupt();
    // Wait for them to stop.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

}
```

Running this should demonstrate one of the problems with your design. Notice that the `P2 Update` rarely gets called. This is because `P1` spends very little time with the lock released and so starves the other thread. See how in `p1` it will `lock.unlock()` and then almost immediately do a `lock.lock()` again as it starts the loop again.

Comment: Hi @OldCurmudgeon, what if `doWork()` is common for above 2 Runnables.  thanks.

Comment: Locks and using synchronized blocks wouldn't be too different here but as you correctly pointed out, the design in general seems to be flawed.

Comment: @AshishPatil - Why would that be a problem? Just move it into a scope where it is accessible to both threads. You could even create it as a lambda if you like.

Comment: Actually, you could solve the problem of starving the other thread by passing `true` to the `ReentrantLock` constructor thus setting it into fair mode. That should allow for a rough fifo order of locks being issued, i.e. `p2` wouldn't get starved by `p1` since at some point `p2` will wait longer for a lock than `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pseudocode, really, but I hope the idea is understandable.

```
ExecutorService es = ...;
Future t1work = new Future(...);
Future t2work = new Future(...);
Future t2update = new Future(...);

es.submit(t1work);
es.submit(t2work);

while (1) {
  if (t1work.isDone() && t2work.isDone())   es.submit(t2update);
  if (t1work.isDone() && t2update.isDone()) es.submit(t1work);
  if (t2work.isDone() && t2update.isDone()) es.submit(t2work);
  Thread.sleep(100);
}
```